# Splitting Akka To Multiple Projects

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming

The traditional way to use Akka is with one project which consists of all the different actors and is being deployed to multiple servers.

I was wondering if there is any way to split the project to multiple standalone projects, something similar to microservices?

Comment: Yes, but the scope of the answer is pretty big and subject to opinion, so probably not likely you will get a good answer here.

Comment: Where can I found good posts about it? Haven't found one yet...